# Adding text to input box with jquery

Tags: javascript

I have an element on the page that looks like:

`<textarea id="note-content" rows="4"></textarea>`

when I try to write some jQuery to add some text to it:

`$('#note-content').val('hi')`

The button to "submit" the value is still greyed out.

[image]

I've tried

```
function setKeywordText(text) {
    var el = document.getElementById("note-content");
    el.value = text;
    var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
    evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
    el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

setKeywordText("test")
```

as a way to "simulate" sending keystrokes to the browser, but that doesn't seem to work either.

any thoughts?

Comment: Try changing `var evt = document.createEvent("Events");` to `var evt = document.createEvent("Event");`. Reference: [MDN web docs Document.createEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent).

Comment: it adds "test", but "add" is still greyed out

Comment: You appear to be using the old standard. Try using the newer standard: [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent). Also, why don't you enable the button yourself without using events?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by javascript

```
<script>
function changetext(){
document.getElementById("note-content").value = "hi";
}
<script>
```

It should def. work. Plus what exactly did you mean by browser simulation?
Am i missing something?

Comment: the "add" button is still greyed out

Answer (score 0):

It appears this problem is occurring because your button is [`disabled`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp).

To solve this you'd remove the `disabled` attribute using [`jQuery.fn.removeAttr`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/), like this:

```
$("#button-id").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Add this solution it to your vanilla JavaScript code, like this:

```
function setKeywordText(text) {
  // disable button
  var btn = document.getElementById("button-id");
  btn.disabled = false;
  // set input value
  var el = document.getElementById("note-content");
  el.value = text;
  // create and dispatch the event
  var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
  evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
  el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

// run the function
setKeywordText("test");
```

Good luck.

Comment: in theory that works, but unfortunately disabling the button causes an error later. It doesn't seem like the page recognizes the content and i'm trying to add an empty box